# Wxpython Switching frames between two python files

Tags: python, wxpython

i have two py files that each have its own frame made using wxPython, MainWindow and RecWindow. MainWindow has the RecWindow python file included using the keyword "recovery".

MainWindow code:

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY,title,pos=(500,200), size = (650,500), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnExit)
    self.SetIcon(wx.Icon('etc\icons\download.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO))
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
```

RecWindow code:

```
class RecWindow(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY,title,pos=(400,200), size = (700,600), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
    self.SetIcon(wx.Icon('etc\icons\download.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO))
    self.count = 0
```

when i click on a button in MainWindow , it will hide the MainWindow create an instance of RecWindow, shown below;

```
def OpenRec(self,event):#this will be used to open the next frame
    OR = recovery(None,-1,"RAVE")
    OR.Show(True)
    MainWindow.Hide()
```

now, what i am unsure of is how i can return to the MainWindow once i close the RecWindow. RecWindow has a cancel and finish button which both map to a self.close() function. How would i then get MainWindow to show itself again?

Answer (score 0):

Use pubsub to send a message to the main window telling it to Show itself again. I actually have an example of how to do that here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Note that this tutorial is using slightly older API that was available in wxPython 2.8. If you're using wxPython 2.9, then you'll have to use the slightly different API that I detail in this article:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of RecWindow keep a reference to it on main_window and bind to its close event.

In the main_window's close handler check if the window closed was the RecWindow.

If it was, clear the reference to it and show the main_window.

Elif the closed window was main_window carry out any required code.

Finally call event.Skip() so the windows get destroyed.

```
import wx


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, (500, 200), (650, 500),
            wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_OPEN)

        panel.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel.sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 7)
        panel.SetSizer(panel.sizer)

        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

        self.rec_window = None

    def on_button(self, event):
        rec_window = RecWindow(self, 'Rec window')
        rec_window.Show()
        self.Hide()
        rec_window.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)
        self.rec_window = rec_window

    def on_close(self, event):
        closed_window = event.EventObject
        if closed_window == self.rec_window:
            self.rec_window = None
            self.Show()
        elif closed_window == self:
            print 'Carry out your code for when Main window closes'
        event.Skip()


class RecWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, (400, 200), (700, 600),
            wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)


app = wx.App(False)
main_window = MainWindow(None, 'Main window')
main_window.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```